# 403 error in accessing/redirecging an URL but works fine in browsers

Tags: python, web-applications, flask, outlook, http-status-code-403

Below is basic web application code snippet simulated from my project it will work as expected to view pdf document from url http://myhost/show_document/sample.pdf, to this web app we required to have SSO(single sign on) authentication so that we have added `before_request` decorator function to this web app to authenticate user before making any request through SSO url which is enterprise specific, Its implemented as shown below.

```
from flask import Flask
import flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/show_document/<report_name>')
def document():
        response = flask.make_response(data) // data is pdf  object
    report_name='sample.pdf'
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        response.headers['Content-Disposition']='inline; filename=report_name'
    return response

@app.before_request
def sso_auth():
    return flask.redirect('https://ssologon-enteriprise.com/ssologinconfirm,html?target={0}'.format(urllib))// this browser redirect to java web application 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
  # Running on http://myhost/
```

above Flask based python web application working as expected.Let's say for example if user click on any url or browse it works as below.

```
steps 1) Browsing url or click on url http://myhost/show_document.pdf (It is Http)
      2) url request will redirect to sso page(which is java based web app). It use Https header 
          3) once SSO login is successful it redirect to its parent(step 1 url) page which is python based with header as (http)
```

our sso is working as expected but Whenever user clicking on url from outlook email body) It giving ||||||403 warning|||||| and web page not getting reload user getting this error warning in server logs. if we copy the url and close and open(restart) the browser then url is working as above steps with out any issue, We facing issue only when we click URL from email body. Please help on figure the issue here are my assumptions.

Is this issue because of http header navigation http original page->https sso page>http original page? Or It is because of SSO java code issue? or Its because of clicking from Outlook email? anybody faced similar issue?

Thanks,In advance

Answer (score 1):

you're passing

`'https://ssologon-enteriprise.com/ssologinconfirm,html?target={0}.format(urllib)'` literally so the `format` bit is within the string.

Fix it like this (move the quote *before* `.format`)

```
'https://ssologon-enteriprise.com/ssologinconfirm,html?target={0}'.format(urllib)
```